# Firebase authentication onCompleteListener not working when passing fragment activity using requireActivity()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, firebase-authentication, android-mvp

In my current project I need to use MVP pattern. I moved Firebase authentication with onCompleteListener from fragment's OnCreateView to separate file UserModel. This listener requires activity to work. I passed activity using fragment's requireActivity() to LoginPresenter. Presenter then passes activity to UserModel, where sign in is performed.

Sign in works but without working listener I have to restart app in order to close login form.

I tried to change Activity in doLogIn to FragmentActivity but that throws "no interface
method doLogIn" error.

---

OnCreateView Fragment:

```
binding.buttonLogin.setOnClickListener {
    loginPresenter.doLogin(requireActivity(), email, password)
}
```

LoginPresenter:

```
override fun doLogin(activity: Activity, email: String, password: String): Boolean {

    user.email = email
    user.password = password

    return user.doLogIn(activity)
}
```

UserModel:

```
override fun doLogIn(activity: Activity): Boolean {
    var isLoggedIn = false

    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(activity) { task ->            // this line is skipped when debugging
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success")
                isLoggedIn = true
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
            }
        }
    return isLoggedIn
}
```

Comment: "In my current project I need to use MVP pattern" -- since user authentication is a UI action, it is not the responsibility of a model in [the model-view-presenter architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter). That is especially true when integrating with a third-party authentication UI, one that you do not control.

Comment: Does that mean that I should keep authentication in fragment instead of moving it to different file? If so, what is the purpose of MVP in this scenario, since model and presenter are not used.

Comment: "Does that mean that I should keep authentication in fragment instead of moving it to different file?" -- personally, that is what I would do. "If so, what is the purpose of MVP in this scenario" -- it has no purpose. Not everything is going to neatly fit within any particular architectural pattern.